# how to write on /sys/ ? Android

Tags: java, android, file-io, root

I'm trying to writte on **"/sys/devices/virtual/timed_output/vibrator/amp"** file.

I can read it just fine, the problem is when i try to writte it.

Here's my code:

```
public static void writeValue(String filename, String value) {
    //FileOutputStream fos = null;
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        /*fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename), false);
        fos.write(value.getBytes());
        fos.flush();*/

        Process p;

        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());  

       os.writeBytes(value + " > " + filename + "\n");
       os.writeBytes("exit\n");

       Log.w(TAG, value + " >> " + filename);

       os.flush();           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Could not write to " + filename);
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Could not close " + filename, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm always getting the feedback from `Log.w(TAG, "Could not write to " + filename);`

How do I proceed about that? Do I have to use some permissions? Has it to be all remade to match root access?

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Well i've not printed it, but since it's a system file i just guess that's a "no no" file to writte xD

I just want to know HOW to do it properly, guessing with root comands, but i dont know how, just need that last part of code to be done

Comment: I there no regular API for that?

Comment: No, there's no api AFAIK to writte system files xD that's dangerous stuff

Comment: I mean, is there no API to turn the vibrator on/off? Or what else are you trying to do?

Comment: Not trying to turn it on/off but increase/decrease the intensity of it, with a motor/rotor that can do that (like GNex or Nexus 4), the intensity is saved on that file, then, if i want to change it, I have to be able to write on system files, since that is a system directory as you may already know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.writeBytes(value + " > " + filename + "\n");
```

is wrong. Try

```
os.writeBytes("echo '"+value + "' > " + filename + "\n");
```

or

```
os.writeBytes("echo -n '"+value + "' > " + filename + "\n");
```

.

Answer (score 3):

Normal SDK applications only have read access to that part of the system. You will need to root your device, and execute commands in a `su` shell to write over there.

Also, the `amp` file doesn't exist on all devices.

Comment: I guessed normal SDK could not writte it (I read it just fine).

I'm rooted obviously, and i'm asking how to change my code to be able to writte on it.

I know about amp file and I do take care of devices that does not have it, the APP is mainly for me and frends, so, i don't care much, still, i've methods implemented to do nothing if file does not exist.

Comment: @Dunnow I've got an open source app [here](https://github.com/RaghavSood/UserManagement) that writes to files on the protected partition using su. You could try modifying the got in that

Comment: I'm watching it, not sure if I understand it

os.writeBytes("pm create-user \"" + name + "\"\n");
os.writeBytes("exit\n");

what is pm create-user or exit\n ?

Comment: @Dunnow Ah that's unrelated to modifying the files. I used the cat command to overwrite files after reading them and modifying the contents.

Comment: well, i don't mind overwritting the file, as long as it's there with the right value on it, can you give me the code snippet to use? It's been a loooong while since I used commands and regular expresions u_u

should i use something like os.writeBytes(value + " > "+fileToWritte +"\n"); ?

Comment: @Dunnow save your data into a file somewhere, and then use: os.writeBytes("cat " + savedFile + " > " destinationFile);

Comment: it's not the same as passing the value directly?

Comment: @Dunnow No, its not. You're replacing one file with another, not editing the existing one. I'm sure there's a way to edit it directly, but I never really bothered looking for it because this worked for me

Comment: code is now executing, but the file does not change at all o_o

Comment: Hmm. Try putting your saved file on the external storage. And make sure you ran `su` before this one.

Comment: Not using a saved file, it HAS to work using the direct value (http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_lts0070.php) may it be the file permissions? even though i'm using root access?

file is rw-r--r-- by default